# nsview through customclass not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsview

I made a CustomView that extends NSView. And a class MyCLass that contains a CustomView.
In below code CustomView viewA is showing correctly. But that same view through MyClass wont show. I got no error but there is nothing on the screen. Anybody knows why?

```
 CustomView* viewA = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 400)];

MyClass *foo;
[foo setFooView:[[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 400)]];
// or [foo setFooView:viewA];

[[self.window contentView] addSubview:viewA]; //IS SHOWING
[[self.window contentView] addSubview:foo.fooview]; //DOES NOT SHOW?
```

.h file of MyClass

```
    #import "CustomView.h"

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    CustomView *fooview;
}
-(CustomView *) fooview;
-(void) setFooView:(CustomView *)input;

@end
```

.m file of MyClass

```
    #import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (CustomView *)fooview {
    return fooview;
}

-(void) setFooView:(CustomView *)input
{
    fooview = input;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually creating an instance of `MyClass` anywhere?  It appears as if you're putting the `CustomView` into a nil object.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put: MyClass *foo = [[MyClass alloc] init];